# [] と["テキスト1", "テキスト2", "テキスト3", "テキスト4"] の違い

Tags: javascript

**Chromeで変数をコンソール表示させた時、下記になることがあるのですが、違いは何でしょうか？**
・何れも配列？
・一次元配列か2次元配列の違い？
・B内容をAみたいに表示するためには、どうすれば良いでしょうか？

---

**A**

> ▼[] 
>   0:"テキスト1"
>   1:"テキスト2" 
>   2:"テキスト3"
>   3:"テキスト4"
>    //中略
>   **proto**: Array[0]

---

**B**

> ▼["テキスト1", "テキスト2", "テキスト3", "テキスト4"] 
>   0: "テキスト1" 
>   1: "テキスト2"
>    2: "テキスト3"
>   3: "テキスト4" 
>   //中略
>   **proto**: Array[0]

---

**折りたたみ**
[image: 折りたたみ]
**展開**
[image: 展開]

Comment: それぞれの二行目以降は展開したときの表示だと思うのですが、一行目の`["テキスト1", "テキスト2", "テキスト3", "テキスト4"] ` などは折りたたんだ状態の表示なのでしょうか。値は適当に塗りつぶしていただいて構わないので、スクリーンショットを載せていただけませんか？例 https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpRxV.png

Comment: スクリーンショットアップロードしました

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Aのような表示を次のコードで再現できました。Chromeのコンソールを表示した状態で、「０にして開始」を押すと、[]だけになりますが、そこで▶を押さずに、「要素を追加」を何度か押してから▶押すと、追加された分だけ要素が出てきます。

```js
var a = [];
document.getElementById('s').addEventListener('click', function(){
  a.length = 0;
  console.log(a);
});
document.getElementById('a').addEventListener('click', function(){
  a.push("hoge");
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="s">０にして開始</button>
  <button id="a">要素を追加</button>
</body>
</html>
```

どうやら、Chromeのコンソールでは、 **コンソール上で表示が必要になったときの配列の状態** を表示するようです。これは▶を押す場合も同様で **▶を押されて▼になったときの配列の状態** が表示されます。つまり、`console.log()`が評価されて、コンソールに表示されたときに要素が空であれば[]になります。しかし、その後に要素が追加されるようなコードが有り、その後に▶を押した場合は、そのとき既に追加された分の要素が▼と共に現れます。この表示の処理は一度きりであり、その後さらに要素を追加しても、表示内容は変更されません。なお、コンソールを出していなかった場合も、コンソールを出したときの状態が反映されるようです(ただし、Array[数字]のような表記になってしまいます)。

Comment: Chromeコンソールにおける正常な挙動なのですね。色々な所からデータを取得していたため、何かおかしな変換処理をしたのかと思い質問したのですが、そうではなかったことが分かりました。大変参考になりました